# Word/phrase for country's Ideology /political syst., whose governing bodies keeps tight control on media, on leak of info regarding mishandling

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Looking for a reasonably official Word or phrase for Ideology /political system of a country, whose governing bodies keeps tight control of its media, its internal affairs and does not let any interference whether human rights or international pressure on their self serving policies. Where laws are passed by parliament tightening media control. Mishandling in the country is beyond scrutiny from outside (international) forces. Pretty much everything is insulated as in "insulated country"

An '...ism' or '...logy' or "...cracy" or "insulated country" like listed word or listed phrase. I believe dictatorship could have been used. But it is rather outsider pressure which is intolerated while internally there is either amicable agreement owing to plain cultural similarities or simply forced cultural obedience typically like a monarchy.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are looking for this word

**Fascism**

> a. A system of government marked by centralization of authority under a dictator, a capitalist economy subject to stringent governmental controls, violent suppression of the opposition, and typically a policy of belligerent nationalism and racism.

> b. A political philosophy or movement based on or advocating such a system of government.

> 2. Oppressive, dictatorial control.

[American Heritage Dictionary]

I offer another candidate because your question depicts an Orwellian state of affairs

**Big Brotherism**

> Authoritarian efforts at total control, as of a person or nation: “the frightening totalitarian Big Brotherism that launched the privacy scare” (Newsweek).

[AHD]

Comment: Fascism is the wrong word to use; it refers to a specific form of nationalist authoritarian government that the OP's hypothetical government might not possess.

Answer (score 0):

#### Authoritarianism.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authoritarianism), authoritarianism is "a form of government characterized by the rejection of political plurality, the use of a strong central power to preserve the political status quo, and reductions in the rule of law, separation of powers, and democratic voting."

A government that controls its media to this sort of extent is definitely using a strong central power to preserve the political status quo along with a reduction in the rule of law and separation of powers.